# how to break one column with huge text data into multiple column or array in sql and php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a database column having questions and answers. I have to get the specific question and its answer from that column.
I have column ques_result =

```
a:3:{i:o;"Is maths easy".&lt;
 br /&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;user-answers&quot;&gt;&lt;br /&gt; &lt;p class=&quot;strongly-disagree&quot; 
&gt;Strongly Disagree&lt;/p&gt; &lt;"Is physics easy".&lt;
 br /&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;user-answers&quot;&gt;&lt;br /&gt; &lt;p class=&quot;strongly-disagree&quot; 
&gt;Strongly Disagree&lt;/p&gt; &lt;
```

Anyone can guide me how can I extract question1 = Is maths easy? then its answer
and question 2 = Is physics easy? then its answer

also can someone guide me what is a:3: in sql? 
This column format is text.

Also I would appreciate if someone guides me using php5 or sqli.

Comment: This looks like a serialized array. See [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) in the PHP manual

Comment: something is missing with this column, am I right ?

Comment: Thank you @RiggsFolly yes I just googled it is something like that. I am new with both php and sql, so I had no clue. But any idea how can I split its value, so I can extract information per question and answer

Comment: @Omis Brown I just copied some bits to give idea what the column has, obviously its just one bit it has like 10 questions and their answers.

Comment: then fetch each column and use unserialize() function to get array representation of it

Comment: if you need better answer and code, you should post actual DB structure and at least one complete column data

Comment: `$array = unserialize($row['column_name']); print_r($array);`

Comment: Thank you so much @RiggsFolly. It worked. Many thanks.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Could you please guide me how can I extract specific information after array un-serialized.  so for example I want to know answer for "Is maths easy". How can I do that?

Comment: Once you have done the `unserialize()` it is a PHP array again. So pick out of the array whatever you are interested in.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am getting an arry now like this [0] => Is maths easy
 [1] => 5 how can I  extract this question and at [1] is its answer. Could you please give an example like you did above.