# how to use specific information from unserialised array in php

Tags: php, sql, arrays, serialization

I have an array that is from unserialized array in php, I have posted this question([how to break one column with huge text data into multiple column or array in sql and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46033724/how-to-break-one-column-with-huge-text-data-into-multiple-column-or-array-in-sql?noredirect=1#comment79033134_46033724)earlier) to understand how unserialize array works from sql data. 
This was my data

```
a:3:{i:o;"Is maths easy".&lt;
 br /&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;user-answers&quot;&gt;&lt;br /&gt; &lt;p class=&quot;strongly-disagree&quot; 
&gt;Strongly Disagree&lt;/p&gt; &lt;"Is physics easy".&lt;
 br /&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;user-answers&quot;&gt;&lt;br /&gt; &lt;p class=&quot;strongly-disagree&quot; 
&gt;Strongly Disagree&lt;/p&gt; &lt;
```

Now I am having issue in getting specific information. 
If I have

```
 [0]
              [0] => Is maths easy
              [1]=> user-answers

    [1] 
              [0]=>Is physics easy
              [1]=> user-answers
```

Now I want to get let say 50 users answered these questions. Some user might left answer empty. I want to make a percentage 
like

```
user who answered/Total users
```

Any clue how can I get this information out of the array I got from unserialzed array.

Comment: Why don't you store the individual entries in your database? Databases are good in working with large sets of data (filtering, combining, calculating). Now you have to do it all in php

Comment: @ Ivo P they are already stored as serialized array in database. its already pre build. I just need to use this info.

Comment: at a second look: it is even worse. This is not serialized data: it is a serialized dump (in html) of some array. So you have a textual presentation of how the dump of the array (using print_r) would look like. And that polluted with html tags. You could take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226057/recreate-original-php-array-from-print-r-output but it is the hard way